# Laravel - calculate selling price from pricelist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a B2B ordering app with a special deal pricelist based on the customer.  The pricelist can have a set price (UnitPrice) OR a discount percentage (DiscountPercentage), not both, for certain stock items. Each product also have a standard price (SellingPrice) that should be used if no discount is applicable.

In the controller, I create a collection consisting of the product code, normal selling price, discount percentage and unitprice, for eg.

```
{
  id: "6",
  StockItemName: "FIRELIGHTERS 24X12 PCS",
  StockCode: "000000000019",
  SellingPrice: "386.600",
  DiscountPercentage: "5.000",
  UnitPrice: "0.00"
},
{
  id: "7",
  StockItemName: "BRIQUETTES 1X4KG",
  StockCode: "000000000020",
  SellingPrice: "39.500",
  DiscountPercentage: "0.000",
  UnitPrice: "35.400",
}
{
  id: "8",
  StockItemName: "BRIQUETTES 1X10KG",
  StockCode: "000000000021",
  SellingPrice: "45.000",
  DiscountPercentage: "0.000",
  UnitPrice: "0.000",
}
```

In the blade view, I have a drop-down select to select the item you want to order and should display the applicable price.  This list can thus contain any combination of products with a percentage discount, products at a discounted price (UnitPrice) and products at the standard price (SellingPrice):

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
   <option value="{{ $product->id }}" {{ $oldProduct == $product->id ? ' selected' : '' }}>
       {{ $product->StockCode }} - {{ $product->StockItemName }} - 
         {{ empty($product->DiscountPercentage) ? 
           ( !empty($product->UnitPrice) ? number_format($product->UnitPrice, 2) 
              : number_format($product->SellingPrice, 2) )
           : number_format($product->SellingPrice - (($product->DiscountPercentage / 100) 
              * $product->SellingPrice), 2) 
         }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

This works correctly for DiscountPercentages but if DiscountPercentage is empty and UnitPrice is not, it displays SellingPrice instead of UnitPrice.

Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of using `empty($product->DiscountPercentage)` use `!floatval($product->DiscountPercentage)` because empty returns false because you have a string